# KVM host, add LV to guest

Tags: lvm, kvm

I have a KVM host with a software RAID 10 array. The software RAID 10 array is a PV on the host and there's a single VG.

I have a couple of LVs used at the host level (a datastore for KVM guest `.img` files).

Normally when adding a new disk to a guest I create the LV on the host then add that to the guest's config. Then `pvcreate` directly on the block device (no partition), `vgcreate`, `lvcreate` and `mkfs` on the new block device within the guest.

I don't bother partitioning the block device before `pvcreate` because it's one less step to do when resizing the LV on the host. I realise the downside is in theory some systems might decide to automatically partition the unpartitioned block device because they don't recognise the LVM metadata, though I have never ever seen this happen in practice.

When resizing the LV on the host the free space in the PV is picked up and I have to `vgextend`, `lvextend` and `resize2fs` in the guest.
I don't suppose there's a way I can skip having LVM running in the guest and just `lvextend` on the host then `resize2fs` in the guest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't suppose there's a way I can skip having LVM running in the guest and just lvextend on the host then resize2fs in the guest?

There's absolutely no requirement to use LVM inside a guest.  You can just use the block device directly.  Using LVM *inside* the guest gets you almost nothing (since you're already using LVM on the host to manage your space).

If by "KVM" you mean "libvirt", you can do use the `virsh blockresize` command to get your guest to recognize the additional space once you've resized a block device.  That is, if I have a guest with an attached LV:

```
</disk><disk type="block" device="disk">
  <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
  <source dev="/dev/tank/foobar"/>
  <backingStore/>
  <target dev="vdb" bus="virtio"/>
  <alias name="virtio-disk1"/></disk>
```

Where:

```
# lvs
  foobar                                      tank           -wi-ao----   4.00g
```

I can add space to the LV on the host:

```
# lvresize -L +2G /dev/tank/foobar
```

Tell libvirt to update the size:

```
# virsh blockresize myguest /dev/tank/foobar --size 0
```

And then inside the guest, resize the filestem:

```
guest# resize2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
Resizing the filesystem on /dev/vdb to 1572864 (4k) blocks.
The filesystem on /dev/vdb is now 1572864 (4k) blocks long.
```

Comment: That's ideal. I thought it was totally pointless having LVM in the guest but wasn't sure if I could write an FS directly to the block device within the guest. Thanks!